# TinyMCE MS MVC looking for non-minified file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, minifiedjs

I have an MS MVC deployment that is looking for a subscript for TinyMCE "theme.js" and not finding it because the file is theme.min.js. How do I get MVC to look for the minified file?

The tinymce file is tinyMCE.min.js, so it is finding that one. Is this a problem with setting TinyMCE or MS MVC?

Long explanation : We are in the process of implementing TinyMCE on a Microsoft MVC page. It was working locally but would not run when deployed to the server. It was failing with a 404, file not found for the file :
 PROJECT_ROOT/bundles/themes/modern/theme.js

This was not the location of the theme file it was looking for and after a little research I found out that you needed to set the tinymce.baseURL property. When I did this it helped a little by changing the location in the error to the actual location of the file :
PROJECT_ROOT/Scripts/libs/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js

The problem is that for some reason it was looking for the un-minified file theme.js and not theme.min.js. If I change the name to theme.js it works.

I thought that MVC and/or TinyMCE would do some magic to get the right name. Is there a setting I need to change?

Comment: With TinyMCE 6 it's the other way around: it's really hard to get it to load skin from an URL that doesn't include coded `.min` in the middle.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set **tinymce.suffix = '.min';** before you init TinyMCE

```
tinymce.suffix = '.min';
tinymce.baseURL = '/js/tinymce';
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#editor',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: 'code' 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE should work out to load minified (or non-minified) files based on which TinyMCE file you load (`tinymce.js` or `tinymce.min.js`).

Not sure what's happening in your case but that logic appears to be failing.

If you grab the DEV package from https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted/ it would come with both the minified and non-minified versions of each file so the editor would find what it needs at runtime.

***Note***:  The code in the minified and non-minified files functions just the same so from a functionality perspective it does not really matter if `theme.min.js` or `theme.js` code is loaded.  It only add ~200K to the file size so even that is immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution for this. There is a property you can set in the tinymce object called "suffix" that resolved this for me.

So, for the first part I set a rootURL property in the page calling TinyMCE, and then added the line tinymce.baseURL = rootURL + 'Scripts/libs/tinymce' just before the tinymce.init.

Then, to get it to find the theme.min.js set tinymce.suffix = '.min'

This seems to have resolved the issue. Not sure if this is a hack solution but it is working. If anyone has a better way to do it please let me know.

Comment: Hi, I am having exact issue that you had. Tell me, what is a rootURL?